# Ajax jquery POST used in next jquery POST

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm calling ajax post function as below:

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $( document ).on( 'click', '.new', function() {     
            $.ajax({
        url: 'zapytanie.php',
        data: {criteria: $(this).attr('id')},
        method: 'POST',
    }).done(function(data){
        console.log(data);  
        var choice= data;
        $("#main-container").load("criterias.php .choice-" + choice + "-details");   

    });

});

    });
```

I'm getting a html page with what I wanted to achieve. The next step for me would be to move forward with another post request. in data I would like to append also the 'choice':

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $( document ).on( 'click', '.choice-next', function() {     
            $.ajax({
        url: 'choice-next.php',
        data: {criteria: choice},
        method: 'POST',
    }).done(function(data){
        console.log(data);  
        $("#main-container").html(data); 

    });


});

    });
```

however when I do it i'm getting message - variable undefined.

How to pass the variable from one post to another within single page?

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a problem with the variable scope. Ideally you should use a [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) for this kind request chaining.

A nice way to store the response information and retrieve it in a different scope is by using [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: I've been looking for something apart local storage did not know it's not possible. For now I've been using cookies to store that data between requests so I can log what step was user in when he leaves the site and comes back later. Could you tell me what's better in that case - cookies or localstorage? What's the advantages/disadvantages?

Answer (score 0):

Declare choice outside your click function that is below document ready. Also you need not to put second function inside separate document ready.

**Update:**

```
<script>
    var choice;
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $( document ).on( 'click', '.new', function() {
                $.ajax({
                url: 'zapytanie.php',
                data: {criteria: $(this).attr('id')},
                method: 'POST',
            }).done(function(data){
                console.log(data);  
                choice = data;
                $("#main-container").load("criterias.php .choice-" + choice + "-details");
            });
        });
        /*----------------------------------*/
        $( document ).on( 'click', '.choice-next', function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'choice-next.php',
                data: {criteria: choice},
                method: 'POST',
            }).done(function(data){
                console.log(data);  
                $("#main-container").html(data);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: does not work - still getting: Uncaught ReferenceError: choice is not defined